# Win32 API tool window

Tags: c, winapi

Can anyone give me an example code for a tool window (with pixel dimensions) for the Win32 API?

Thanks

Comment: you can find this on msdn easily, search first, ask later :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tool windows are just windows with the WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW extended style:

```
hWnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW, szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 100, 100, 500, 400, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
```

Note you need to use CreateWindow**Ex** to use extended styles. The above is a 500x400 window at 100,100 on the screen.

Comment: If you want a full example then [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/22257420/Programming/Toolwindow.zip) is the full visual studio solution. Completely overkill as it is essentially the basic template with one line changed (as shown above).

Comment: I had this, but how do I know what `szWindowClass` is.

Comment: that's the window class that you registered before calling CreateWindow.

Comment: Ok, it doesn't get any more simple than [this](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/22257420/Toolwindow.zip). Making windows using the winapi is not a one line thing unfortunately,

Comment: @Midas If you aren't familiar with how to create a window in low-level Win32 then you really need to spend a bit of time doing some background reading. Otherwise you'll have a lot of problems. This kind of stuff is much easier with a framework (e.g. WinForms, VCL etc.)

Comment: @Mat Thanks for the example. +1 But how can I make the tool window as child for my main window? I can't get this working.

Comment: I'm sorry. It didn't work because of a spelling mistake in the window class name. Now it works!

Comment: Good to see you got it sorted. As it has already been mentioned, making windows with the winapi is not simple, I spent a lot of time programming in AutoIt before I tried, and even though it helped, it still took me a while to figure it all out.

Comment: Wanted to add this, because this is what I eventually use: If you don't want to make the toolwindow as your main window, I suggest you use the following (where hWnd is the handle for your main window): `CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW, szToolWndClass, "Title", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 240, 320, hWnd, NULL, hInstance, NULL)`